# configure round cube with action mailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

How to configure roundcube mail service with rails application ?
Write the code required for production.rb , I am trying the following code:

```
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: '3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :address => "webmail.xxx.com",
      :port => 25,
      # :domain => "xxx.com",
      :authentication => :login,
      :user_name => 'xxx',
      :password => 'xxx',
      :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
  }
```